# Obtaining the state of a GitHub repository

Tags: github

What is the best way to record the current state of a GitHub repository so that I can reproduce results later? Never mind branches. I only care about *main*.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a new branch based on the current one, and then go back to main and work on it, but in github itself it is possible to check the history, so it is possible to revert the changes if you want, is that more or less what you are looking for?